# Hide Columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 2 sheets, and in sheet1 on cell B5 I have a value that changes automatically according other cell. And my goal is to hide columns Y:AN or AQ:BF on sheet2 if B5 on sheet1 is 3 or 2 respectively. I applied the code below, but doesnt work when I protect sheet2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B5" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "3"
            Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "2"
            Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Else
            Union(Columns("Y:AN"), Columns("AQ:BF")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Either unprotect/protect programmatically, or change the protection to be `UserOnlyInterface:=True`.

Comment: If you change the value from 3 to 2 it will not unhide columns "Y:AN".  Is that intentional?

Comment: You say _cell B5 I have a value that changes automatically according other cell_. Does that mean B5 contains a formula?  If so, B5 changing won't fire the Change event.  You'll need to use the Calculate event.  There are many posts about that on SO

Comment: If the event does fire, and the code is in `Sheet1` (which it must be to respond to `Sheet1!B5` changing) then your code will hide columns on `Sheet1`.  You'll need to qualify them with the required worksheet reference

Comment: Also, your code will error if >1 cells are changed at once, eg with a Copy/Paste

Answer (score 0):

use unprotect method in your code and protect after prcedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B5" Then
    thisworkbook.worksheets("").unprotect  ' enter sheet name, if protected by password .unprotect("password")
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "3"
            Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case "2"
            Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Case Else
            Union(Columns("Y:AN"), Columns("AQ:BF")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
    thisworkbook.worksheets("").protect   ' enter sheet name, if protected by password .protect("password") //check docs
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

protect method concerns worksheets not sheets. You need add fragment

```
worksheets(NAME).protect(password)
```

for example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
dim ws as worksheet
dim password as string
password = "qwerty"  ' add password
set ws=thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet2")
If Range("B5").Value = "2" Then 
Sheet2.Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "3" Then 
Sheet2.Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
Else Sheet2.Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Sheet2.Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 
End If 
ws.protect(password )
End Sub
```